# Sort and mix with different attributes

Tags: django, postgresql, sorting

I have a list of products, each have a price, a discount and categories.

I need to sort this list starting with the first product with a price less than a certain target and descending in price.

The complication is that I also need to mix categories and discounts. That is, consecutive products must have different categories. Also there should be two products with discount, then two without discount and so on.

I would like to get something like this:

```
product_a, 9000, 10%, category_x
product_b, 8000, 10%, category_z
product_c, 7000,  0%, category_y
product_d, 6000,  0%, category_w
product_d, 5000, 10%, category_x
```

Any ideas how to do this without having to do many queries.

This is for a site made with Django and using Postgresql

Comment: your sample is data or wanted sorted result?..

Comment: The sample is the sorted result I need

Comment: and the data sample please?

Comment: The data could be just the same but with no particular order. In the real system there are about 2000 products and they have more attributes but those in the question are the ones relevant to the ordering I need.

Comment: And you need to pick random products out of the 50,000 that matches the pattern above?  If not: how can you be sure that the price will be descending?

Comment: What I did at the moment was to sort by category and price, then use itertools.groupby to group by category and get one from each iterator given by groupby